# Need Nextjs <Link> to behave as <a> tag

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have Link to dynamic page as such:

```
 <Link href={`/event/${event.slug}`}>
      <a className="event-card">
        <img
          className="img-fluid"
          alt={event.name}
          src={event.event_main_image ? event.event_main_image : defaultEventImg}
        ></img>
      </a>
 </Link>
```

Problem arises when I go to this page through Link and click back and go to another similar dynamic page, there is no refresh of content.
Specificly there is a javascript webshop file that get's added to this page and when there is no refresh there is all sorts of buggy behaviour happening.

When I take Link element out and just use a tag like so:

```
      <a href={`/event/${event.slug}` className="event-card">
        <img
          className="img-fluid"
          alt={event.name}
          src={event.event_main_image ? event.event_main_image : defaultEventImg}
        ></img>
      </a>
```

then everything works, shop works, no buggy behaviour. Problem then is I cant run build with a tags as Nextjs compiler gives you error and tells you to replace a tags with Link.

So my question is how can I get a tag behaviour using Link component?